# English ruler recursion issue

Tags: java, function, recursion

I am trying t dry run the English ruler method from book, but dry run is a bit confusing and my output and original output are different.

```
public static void drawRuler(int nInches, int majorlength)
{
  drawLine(majorLength, 0);
  for (int j =1; j<= nInches, j++)
  {
   drawInterval(majorLength-1);
   drawLine(majorLength, j);
 }
}

private static void drawInterval (int centralLength)
{
 if (centralLength>=1)
 {
  drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
  drawLine(centralLength);
  drawInterval(centrakLength-1);
 }
}

public static void drawLine(int tickLength, int tickLabel)
{
 for (int j=0; j<ticklength; j++)
   System.out.print("-")
 if (tickLabel>=0)
  System.out.print(" "+tickLable);
 System.out.print("\n");
}

private static void drawLine(int tickLength)
{
  drawLine(tickLength, -1);
}
```

In the first go, I am entering `nInches = 1 and majorlength 3`,

1- drawLine will be called with (3,0)   // tick length and ticklabel

```
public static void drawLine(3, 0)
    {
     for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
       System.out.print("-")
     if (tickLabel>=0)
      System.out.print(" "+tickLable);
     System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

output:

```
--- 0
```

2- Now below loop will run from drawRuler function

```
for (int j =1; j<=1, j++)
      {
       drawInterval(majorLength-1);
```

*** Point1: Mean above line will call drawInterval(2) ?***

```
drawLine(majorLength, j);
     }
```

3- We move to function drawInterval with 2 as argument

```
private static void drawInterval (2)
    {
     if (centralLength>=1)   // true
     {
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
 **Point 2: what the point of calling same function with 1 ? and will it call itself again without drawing anything? and function will go on nextline after drawInterval become 0?**


drawLine(centralLength);
      drawInterval(centrakLength-1);
     }
    }
```

Point3: `drawLine(tickLength, -1);` Why we use this `-1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have taken your code from the book [Data Structures and Algorithms in Java](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=UqmYAgAAQBAJ&ots=p6G6-D_ew0&hl=en&pg=PA193#v=onepage&q&f=true).

But your code does not even compile, there are so many syntax errors and variable misnomers. Did you get that source code from the book via scan + OCR without trying to run it with Java?

So first let us fix the errors and turn this fragmentary code into a class with a main method, shall we?

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class EnglishRuler {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawRuler(2, 4);
  }

  public static void drawRuler(int nInches, int majorLength) {
    drawLine(majorLength, 0);
    for (int j = 1; j <= nInches; j++) {
      drawInterval(majorLength - 1);
      drawLine(majorLength, j);
    }
  }

  private static void drawInterval(int centralLength) {
    if (centralLength >= 1) {
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
      drawLine(centralLength);
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
    }
  }

  private static void drawLine(int tickLength, int tickLabel) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tickLength; j++)
      System.out.print("-");
    if (tickLabel >= 0)
      System.out.print(" " + tickLabel);
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  private static void drawLine(int tickLength) {
    drawLine(tickLength, -1);
  }
}
```

`drawRuler(1, 3)` prints:

```
--- 0
-
--
-
--- 1
```

`drawRuler(1, 5)` prints:

```
----- 0
-
--
-
---
-
--
-
----
-
--
-
---
-
--
-
----- 1
```

`drawRuler(2, 4)` prints:

```
---- 0
-
--
-
---
-
--
-
---- 1
-
--
-
---
-
--
-
---- 2
```

This is all as expected. Now let us add some optional debug output to the program:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class EnglishRuler {
  private static boolean DEBUG = true;
  private static String indent = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawRuler(1, 3);
  }

  public static void drawRuler(int nInches, int majorLength) {
    if (DEBUG)
      System.out.println("drawRuler(" + nInches + ", " + majorLength + ")");
    drawLine(majorLength, 0);
    for (int j = 1; j <= nInches; j++) {
      drawInterval(majorLength - 1);
      drawLine(majorLength, j);
    }
  }

  private static void drawInterval(int centralLength) {
    indent += "  ";
    if (DEBUG)
      System.out.println(indent + "drawInterval(" + centralLength + ")");
    if (centralLength >= 1) {
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
      drawLine(centralLength);
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
    }
    indent = indent.substring(2);
  }

  private static void drawLine(int tickLength, int tickLabel) {
    indent += "  ";
    if (DEBUG)
      System.out.println(indent + "drawLine(" + tickLength + ", " + tickLabel + ")");
    for (int j = 0; j < tickLength; j++)
      System.out.print("-");
    if (tickLabel >= 0)
      System.out.print(" " + tickLabel);
    System.out.print("\n");
    indent = indent.substring(2);
  }

  private static void drawLine(int tickLength) {
    drawLine(tickLength, -1);
  }
}
```

This does not change the output as long as `DEBUG` is `false`. If you set it to `true`, the log for `drawRuler(1, 3)` becomes:

```
drawRuler(1, 3)
  drawLine(3, 0)
--- 0
  drawInterval(2)
    drawInterval(1)
      drawInterval(0)
      drawLine(1, -1)
-
      drawInterval(0)
    drawLine(2, -1)
--
    drawInterval(1)
      drawInterval(0)
      drawLine(1, -1)
-
      drawInterval(0)
  drawLine(3, 1)
--- 1
```

There you have an automatically generated version of your dry run.

So as for your questions:

> In the first go, I am entering `nInches = 1` and `majorlength = 3`,
>
> 1) `drawLine` will be called with `(3,0)` (`tickLength` and `tickLabel`)

Correct.

> Point1: Mean above line will call `drawInterval(2)`?

Correct.

> Point3: `drawLine(tickLength, -1)`. Why we use this `-1`?

Because in `drawLine(int tickLength, int tickLabel)` it says:

```java
    if (tickLabel >= 0)
      System.out.print(" " + tickLabel);
```

So making the value for `tickLabel` smaller than zero is just a way to avoid printing the label when we are not at the main interval but at a smaller sub-interval in between.

---

**Update:** I have also added indentation according to recursion level to the version of the program with debug output and also updated the log output to be indented for the OP's better understanding.

---

**Update 2:** You can simplify the program by inlining the convenience method `drawLine(int tickLength)` as follows:

```java
  private static void drawInterval(int centralLength) {
    // ...
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
      drawLine(centralLength, -1);  // Note the additional ", -1"
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
    // ...
  }
```

And then delete this one as now it is no longer in use:

```
  // Delete me!
  private static void drawLine(int tickLength) {
    drawLine(tickLength, -1);
  }
```

---

**Update 3:** Because you seem to be so irritated that I did not print log output for the convenience method `drawLine(int tickLength)`, here is yet another extended version of the original program generating output for that method too, now exactly replicating your pen & paper dry run:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class EnglishRuler {
  private static boolean DEBUG = true;
  private static String indentText = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    drawRuler(1, 3);
  }

  public static void drawRuler(int nInches, int majorLength) {
    debugPrint("drawRuler(" + nInches + ", " + majorLength + ")");
    drawLine(majorLength, 0);
    for (int j = 1; j <= nInches; j++) {
      drawInterval(majorLength - 1);
      drawLine(majorLength, j);
    }
  }

  private static void drawInterval(int centralLength) {
    indent();
    debugPrint("drawInterval(" + centralLength + ")");
    if (centralLength >= 1) {
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
      drawLine(centralLength);
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
    }
    dedent();
  }

  private static void drawLine(int tickLength, int tickLabel) {
    indent();
    debugPrint("drawLine(" + tickLength + ", " + tickLabel + ")");
    for (int j = 0; j < tickLength; j++)
      System.out.print("-");
    if (tickLabel >= 0)
      System.out.print(" " + tickLabel);
    System.out.print("\n");
    dedent();
  }

  private static void drawLine(int tickLength) {
    indent();
    debugPrint("drawLine(" + tickLength + ")");
    drawLine(tickLength, -1);
    dedent();
  }

  private static void debugPrint(String message) {
    if (DEBUG)
      System.out.println(indentText + message);
  }

  private static void indent() {
    indentText += "  ";
  }

  private static void dedent() {
    indentText = indentText.substring(2);
  }
}
```

The updated console log becomes:

```
drawRuler(1, 3)
  drawLine(3, 0)
--- 0
  drawInterval(2)
    drawInterval(1)
      drawInterval(0)
      drawLine(1)
        drawLine(1, -1)
-
      drawInterval(0)
    drawLine(2)
      drawLine(2, -1)
--
    drawInterval(1)
      drawInterval(0)
      drawLine(1)
        drawLine(1, -1)
-
      drawInterval(0)
  drawLine(3, 1)
--- 1
```

I found that unnecessary, but if it helps you I am glad.

Comment: Thank you for such an explanation. Yes, I took the code from the book and I did not try it on the tool because I am trying to learn the dry-runs. The only query I left is on this condition ` if (centralLength >= 1) {
      drawInterval(centralLength - 1);
      drawLine(centralLength);` when `drawinterval(centralLength-1)` makes central length value equal to `0` then how it will run `drawLine(centralLength);` because condition will become false as central length is not greater than or equal to 1. `if (centralLength >= 1)`

Comment: From the code : `drawInterval(centralLength - 1); drawLine(centralLength); drawInterval(centralLength - 1);`, Line 1 (`drawInterval(centralLength - 1);` ) makes the `central length=1` then drawLine calls it as 1 with output `1` then 3rd line (`drawInterval(centralLength - 1);`) wil execute as `1-1=0` so control will back to loop now? isnt it?

Comment: I agree that dry-runs for basic algorithms are a good learning tool, but you don't learn driving by imagining it and don't learn programming by dry-runs only. So I am encouraging you to type your code into an editor or IDE, compile, run, debug and analyse it. You have far better learning opportunities and much shorter feedback cycles than by Copying source code from a book into a SO question, asking theoretical questions which I already answered by printing the debug log for you. _(To be continued...)_

Comment: As for your question, I don't understand it. As a programmer you need to learn to express yourself more precisely in prose (or let code speak). I read your comments above 3x, but by no stretch of imagination can I do more than speculate what you might be asking. I am sure if I understood the question I could answer it because the algorithm is quite simple and also nicely explained in your book.

Comment: **Update:** I have also added indentation according to recursion level to the version of the program with debug output and also updated the log output to be indented for your better understanding. Please check my answer again, maybe now you understand your dry-run better.

Comment: My question was `drawLine(2, -1)` how this 2 comes this function drawLine, on 9th line, before `--` , anyways Thank you

Comment: Honestly, this is quite simple, I barely know how to explain even more. If you cannot do this dry run in your mind, run the program and step through it in a debugger. The call succession (skipping other branches in the call tree) leading to your line of interest is `drawRuler(1, 3)` -> `drawLine(3, 0)` -> `drawInterval(2)` -> `drawLine(2)` -> `drawLine(2, -1)`. As you might have noticed, my program does not print `drawLine(2)` because `drawLine(tickLength)` is only syntactic sugar, a utility to always call `drawLine(tickLength, -1)`. Just do the dry run on pen + paper, man! It is so easy.

Comment: Actually `drawLine(centralLength)` is called only once, the whole convenience method could be inlined to then read `drawLine(centralLength, -1)`, then there would not two overloaded `drawLine` methods anymore but only one. I only kept that other method because the original author introduced it.

Comment: **Update 3:** Because you seem to be so irritated that I did not print log output for the convenience method `drawLine(int tickLength)`, here is yet another extended version of the original program generating output for that method too, now exactly replicating your pen & paper dry run - see above. I am done here now. Either you decide I deserve your bounty or you can wait for someone to explain it better. I have run out of ideas how to explain even more.

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex, I understand it now.